# JTAPI for CUCM Multi Cluster

Tags: java, cisco-jtapi

**How to use JTAPI for multi-cluster of CUCM (Cisco Unified Communication Manager)?**

As my understanding, if there is only one cluster, I should create a JTAPI Provider instance for the cluster, and work on it for making calls, monitoring calls. But if there are many clusters (I think this is general case in can enterprise),

1. how to use the JTAPI (which one is supported by Cisco JTAPI)?

   1.1 create a JTAPI provider instance for each cluster

   1.2 only one JTAPI provider instance is needed
2. if the case if `1.2`, how to build the server connection string (Which way is provided by Cisco)?

   2.1 fill all the CTI mansgers IP addresses in the string

   2.2 only a virtual IP address for the multi-cluster

Answer (score 1):

got the answer form Cisco Devnet Community. please refer to https://communities.cisco.com/thread/52155

Comment: Please include both the answer and link.  Links tend to die over time - and frequently with Cisco!